# Passing parameter as control number and get table name

Tags: bash

I have a scenario where there is a file with control number and table name, hereby an example:

```
1145|report_product|N|N| 
1156|property_report|N|N
```

I need to pass the control number as 1156 and have to get table name as PR once I get the table name as PR then I need to add some text on that.

Please help

Comment: Please add some piece of your code (working or not) to help us better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work in two stages:

1. You need to find the line, containing 1156.
2. You need to get the information from that line.

In order to find the line (as already indicated by [Juranir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10424004/juranir-santos)), you can use `grep`:

```
Prompt> grep "1156" control.txt
1156|property_report|N|N
```

In order to get the information from that line, you need to get the second column, based on the vertical line (often referred as a "pipe" character), for which there are different approaches. I'll give you two:

1. The `cut` approach: you can cut a line into different parts and take a character, a byte, a column, .... In this case, this is what you need:

   ```
    grep "1156" control.txt | cut -d '|' -f 2

    -d '|' : use the vertical line as a column separator
    -f 2   : show the second field (column)
   ```
2. The `awk` approach: `awk` is a general "text modifier" with multiple features (showing parts of text, performing basic calculations, ...). For this case, it can be used as follows:

   ```
    grep "1156" control.txt | awk -F '|' '{print $2}'

    -F '|'       : use the vertical line as a column separator
    '{print $2}' : the awk script for showing the second field.
   ```

Oh, by the way, I've edited your question. You might press the <kbd>edit</kbd> button in order to learn how I did this :-)

For getting only the first letters, separated by the underscores:

```
grep "1156" control.txt | awk -F '|' '{print $2}' | awk -F '_' '{print substr($1,1,1) substr($2,1,1)}'
```

(something like that)

Comment: Thank you however  I have used awk -F"|" '{print toupper ($2)}' rms_resa_control.dat this command it would work only thing I need first character of the table after pipe limiter. it sohuld be SR

Comment: Any feedback on this

Comment: What do you mean by "SR"? The name is "property_report", isn't it?

Comment: second field is table name that is property_report i need upper case table as name as PR. suppose if it is proeprty_report_people then i should get PRP

Comment: It should be possible to split the name, based on the underscore as a field delimiter, you might use `awk` for that and `awk` has a `substr()` function for getting a limited number of characters from a string (like `substr("ABCD", 1, 1)` which yields "A".

Comment: in this script where should I apply substr

Comment: awk -F"|" '{print toupper ($2)}' rms_resa_control.dat

Comment: Please check my last edit, I've added a new command.

Comment: Thank you so much it really works. Thank you however I need out put should be in upper case also in second field i mean in table name not only up to two underscore.

Comment: if it is more than two underscore also it should work

Comment: Yeah I got out put as upper case

Comment: But it should not work only for first two header of the file. If it is more also it should work. any idea

Comment: You might need a for-loop in your last `awk`, but my knowledge of `awk` is quite limited.

Comment: Avoid useless `grep|awk`:  `awk <control.txt -F \| "/^$1/"'{print $2}' ....`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the controll file is:

```
# cat controlfile.txt
1145|report_product|N|N
1156|property_report|N|N
```

To fine some line you can use:

```
grep 1156 controlfile.txt
```

If needed you can save it to a variable: result=$(grep 1156 file.txt)

Assuming you need to add append something on this line.... you can use:

```
sed '/^1156/s/$/ 123/' controlfile.txt
```

This example will add "123" at the end of line that start with 1156

If needed, add more details like what output you want or anything else to help us better understand your need.